# filter object by keys then flatten it to an array

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an object by it's keys then flatten it to an array so I ended up with this code:

```
Object.keys(
    Object.keys(x)
    .filter((key) => allowed.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = x[key];
        return obj;
    }, {})
).reduce(
    (r, k) => r.concat(k, choices[k]), []
);
```

Is there any other way to do it without calling Object.keys twice?

Thanks in advance.

#Edit:

Sorry for not providing the data, and I forgot to mention that I want it to be sorted as well.

For example I want this :

```
{
  "b": [
    "b1",
    "b2",
    "b3"
  ],
  "v": [
    "v1",
    "v2",
    "v3"
  ],
  "a": [
    "a1",
    "a2",
    "a3"
  ]
}
```

To be like this:

```
["a", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b", "b1", "b2", "b3"]
```

`allowed` is : `["a", "b"]`

Comment: please add the data.

Comment: Show us your object so we can see what are you dealing with.

Comment: Sure: [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)([Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)(yourobj).filter(do your work here))

Comment: I don't even see the need for the first `reduce` call. You take the keys of `x`, filter them, then make a new object with the filtered keys and their values from `x` and...take its keys again? Isn't it the same as `Object.keys(x).filter(/* only allowed */).reduce((r, k)  => r.concat(k, choices[k]), [] )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is something very strange in your data, the following code is completely unnecessary:

```js
Object.keys(x)
    .filter((key) => allowed.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = x[key];
        return obj;
    }, {})
```

It will take the object `x`, filter its keys and create a new object with filtered values from it:

```js
const x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const allowed = ["a", "c"];

const y = Object.keys(x)
  .filter((key) => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = x[key];
      return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(y); // {a: 1, c: 3};
```

However, after all that, you just take the keys of the new object again. This is a useless operation, it can all be shortened to

```js
Object.keys(x)
    .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
    .reduce(
        (r, k) => r.concat(k, choices[k]), []
    );
```

This however, leaves another useless call to `.reduce`. Unless you're constrained to pre-ES2019 versions, you can just [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for this:

```js
Object.keys(x)
    .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
    .flatMap(k => [k, ...choices[k]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

```
Array.from(Object.entries(x).filter(x=>allowed.includes(x[0])).map(x=>x[1]));
// map "1" for values, "0" for keys or map {x[0]:x[1]} 
// to return an array of objects representing the filtered key=>value pairs.
//where "x" is the object
```

here is a code pen test as well:
https://codepen.io/altruios/pen/eYzpNxj